# How to mimic Reminders emoji keyboard behavior?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

In my iOS app, I want users to name things they create using emoji only. Ideally, when the special text field becomes active, I want the emoji keyboard to be presented, but without an option to change the language. I've been under the impression it's simply not possible to force this until I found out that's exactly what standard iOS 14 Reminders app does.

[image]

When editing the list of reminders, one may tap smiling face and choose one of the emojis. Notice how there's no globe to switch the language.
How can I achieve the same in UIKit or SwiftUI? I don't see any "emoji" [UIKeyboardType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype)

Comment: Sadly for you, Apple's apps often use APIs that are not available to third-party developers. That's almost certainly what you're seeing in Reminders.

Comment: Does this your answere : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66397959/14733292

Comment: @robmayoff that's a bummer... I'll have to come up with different design then

Comment: @RajaKishan not really, my goal is to replicate the behavior from Reminders app that's apparently requires some special keyboard type